# SQL: 4 classes must reference one central class which provides database access

Tags: mysql, sql, debugging, nullpointerexception

I want to make several entries into a MySQL database. Because Some of the tables reference others via foreign key I have to get back the inserted ID to inject them in my next statements.

I have 4 classes:

LodgerFormTest
RentForm
RentObject
House

and the class which inserts the MySQL statements into the db: sql_statements

When I want to send a SQL statement I am getting a nullPointer Exception!

The Action listener of the House-class (this is the first sql-statement I have to send) looks like this:

```
         saveButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
              public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                System.out.println("saveButton");

//              sql_statements statements = new sql_statements();               
                sql_statements.performHouse(strasse.getText(), plz.getText(), ort.getText());

                mainmenu.create();
                rentnerFrame.dispose();

              }
            });
```

all methods and variables I am using in sql_statements are static! Therefore I am not instantiating an object.

here is the method "performHouse" in sql_statements

```
public static void performHouse(String strasse, String plz, String ort) {

    String sql = "insert into haus(strasse, plz, ort) values (?,?,?)";
    System.out.println(sql);

    try{
         ps = connect.prepareStatement(sql, ps.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);

         ps.setString(1, strasse);
         ps.setString(2, plz);
         ps.setString(3, ort);

         ps.execute();
         rs = ps.getGeneratedKeys();

         if(rs != null && rs.next()) {
                // Retrieve the auto generated key(s).
                key_idhaus = rs.getLong(1);
                System.out.println("idhaus: " + key_idhaus);
                }


         }catch(Exception ex){
             System.out.println(ex);
         }


} // close performHouse-methode
```

I cant debug because I get a "Source not found." error in the debug view.
Can anybody help please?

Comment: simple solution would be to use a stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

okay I just wanted to finish the task so I implemented a solution which surely is all but not OO:

I implemented redundant code into all of the 4 classes and every class implements their own sql statements. quick and dirty ;)